# LD_PRELOAD with dlsym(malloc) only sometimes causes recursion?

Tags: c, recursion, malloc, ld-preload

I'm trying to make my own code for tracking memory allocation from malloc/calloc/etc and I'm getting inconsistent results,

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE     // for some GNU extensions

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
//#include <pthread.h>

static void* (*real_malloc)(size_t size);
void* (*real_calloc)(size_t nitems, size_t size);
void* (*real_realloc)(void *ptr, size_t size);
void (*real_free)(void *ptr);

int g_init = 0;

__attribute__((constructor))
void injector_init()
{
    fprintf(stderr, "injector init\n");
    if (!g_init)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "calling dlsym(malloc)\n");
        real_malloc = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");
        fprintf(stderr, "returning from dlsym(malloc)\n");
        real_calloc = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "calloc");
        real_realloc = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "realloc");
        real_free = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "free");
        
    }
    if (!real_malloc || !real_calloc || !real_realloc || !real_free)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot find real the real symbols\n");
        return;
    }
    g_init = 1;
}

void* malloc(size_t size)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "malloc()\n");
    if (!g_init)
    {
        printf("Init did not pass\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "malloc was hijacked! allocating %zu memory!\n", size);
    return real_malloc(size);
}


void* calloc(size_t nitems, size_t size)
{
    if (!g_init)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "calloc init failure\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "calloc was hijacked! allocated %li memory!\n", nitems* size);
    return real_calloc(nitems, size);
}
void* realloc(void* ptr, size_t size)
{
    if (!g_init)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "realloc init failure\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "realloc was hijacked! allocated %zu memory!\n", size);
    return real_realloc(ptr, size);
}

void free(void* ptr)
{
    if (!g_init)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Did not find real_free(%p)\n", ptr);
        return;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "free was hijacked mem=%p was used\n", ptr);

    real_free(ptr);
}
```

Sometimes this will trigger a call to malloc/calloc to allocate memory, which means I have to reroute this call to a static memory so that dlsym function returns properly, but sometimes it doesn't require memory and will just return the real malloc address, why?

i use this to compile:

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -O0 -o injector.so injector.c \
        -lpthread -ldl
```

and this as my test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char* array = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
  char* array2 = (char *)calloc(200, sizeof(char));
  char* array3;
  
  printf("Running Test program...\n");
  
  strcpy(array, "TST: This means malloc worked");
  printf("%s\n", array);
  
  strcpy(array2, "TST: This means calloc worked");
  printf("%s, mem=%p\n", array2,array2);
  
  array3 = (char *)realloc(array2, sizeof(char) * 300);
  strcat(array3, " and realloc too!");
  printf("%s, mem=%p\n", array3,array3);
  
  printf("malloc array4\n");
  char* array4 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*600);
  
  printf("freeing memory\n");
  free(array);
  free(array2);
  free(array3);
  free(array4);
  
  
  
  return 0;
}
```

i just used this to run the .so file

```
LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/injector.so ./tester 2> error.txt
```

Comment: Please provide a [complete minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In particular, is there any code before the `dlsym` call, such as `printf`? Those can call `malloc` internally.

Comment: i edited my post with the rest of the code. No, i don't use printf, since i know it would cause problems, i just used fprintf.

Comment: Use `write`, not `fprintf`.

Comment: Functions `dlopen`, `dlsym` and `*printf` _might_ call `malloc`, but aren't bound to do so. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior